# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS WiFi problem (disconnecting)

Tags: wireless

Today, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. For the first 20-30 minutes, WiFi worked perfectly, than suddenly disconnected. I got a message that I'm offline. Now I can't find my WiFi network in Wireless connection list. I've tried many solutions but none worked.

Please help. If needed, I can post info with your commands in terminal. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` to restart Network Manager?

Comment: "sudo: systemctl: command not found"

Comment: Try `sudo service network-manager restart` then.

Comment: didn't work, 1 day ago i tried many solutions like apt get update or blacklisting